# I need to recreate Excel's BinomDIst function in c# for large numbers

Tags: c#, .net, statistics

As the title says. This is an overflow problem. In c# the code I have written is:

```
        private double BinomDist(int successes, int trials, double probability)
        {
            double result = (factorial(trials) / (factorial(successes)*factorial(trials-successes))) * Math.Pow(probability,successes) * Math.Pow(1-probability, trials-successes);
            return result;
        }

        private double factorial(int n)
        {
            if(n == 0)
                return 1;
            double result = 1;
            while(n != 1)
            {
                result = result * Convert.ToDouble(n);
                n = n - 1;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Which works and gives me the CDF probability. But if I have a large number of trials then the sub-calculations of the factorials enter an overflow. So I need some way of having like a long double or a double double datatype or something.

It seems that excel might be doing some mathematical cancellation inside it's BinomDist function to avoid this?

Comment: Not sure why `factorial` is using `double` when by definition, it can only return an integer.   However, you could look at using `System.Numerics.BigInteger`, which was specifically designed for handling big integers, and does it pretty quickly. You could also do some reading about how to calculate binomial distributions, as there are ways of doing it without having to handle the intermediate large numbers

Comment: Also, f you search for `c# binomial distribution`, you'll find that a lot of people have been here before you and solved the problem. Unless you're doing this for self-education (a worthwhile goal in itself), why not pick up code someone else has already written and tested?

Comment: Andrew, consider working with logarithms to avoid large intermediate results; recall that log(a b) = log(a) + log(b).